# vs code c++ breakpoint cannot work in mac

Tags: c++, macos, debugging, visual-studio-code

my os version is sierra 10.12.1 and vs code version is 1.8.1. I installed c++ plugin in vs code. And then I created a c++ project.
There was my c++ source file.

my_simple.cc

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("%s\n", "******begin******");
    int a = 1;
    int b = a;
    printf("%s\n", "******end******");
    return 0;
}
```

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "preLaunchTask": "pre_compile",
            "showDisplayString": true,
            "name": "my_debug",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}.o",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tasks.json

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "g++",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
    ],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "echoCommand": true,
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "pre_compile",
            "args": [
                "${file}",
                "-o${file}.o"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I add some breakpoints to my_simple.cc and then press f5 to compile and run it. The breakpoints did not work as expected. Please help me find the mistake in my code. Thanks

Comment: Where do you set the breakpoints?  The compiler may be optimizing the variable out of existence (you never use them).

Comment: Note that the compiler *can* optimize your function to: `int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    fputs("******begin******\n******end******\n",stdout); return 0
}` - but that level of aggression is unusual.

Comment: I try to add 'printf("%i\n", b);', and then set the breakpoint. But the breakpoint still cannot work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) create new CMakeList.txt with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(FirstProgram)
set(SOURCE Hello.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE})
```

2) Task.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "sh",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-c"],
    "showOutput": "always",
    "suppressTaskName": true,
    "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/build"
    },
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "cmake",
            "args": ["cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug .."]     
        },
        {
            "taskName": "make",
            "args": ["make -j 8"],
            "isBuildCommand": true            
        }
    ]
}
```

3) launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {

            "showDisplayString": true,
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/Build/FirstProgram",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

4) Task Run --> cmake and then: make